# Intent from multiple Activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have problem about getting data from multiple activities.
Here's my problem.

1. I made 3 Activities to get data from each other.(Let me say 3 Activities A,B,C)
   A, B execute different method but their results are same type, the ArrayList.
   I have a purpose to get both results in C from A,B.

Activity-A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RouteInfoDebug1.this, LiveLocationInfo.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArrayList("stdid", (ArrayList<String>) list);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
Log.d("LLNC", "Passed Value:" + (ArrayList<String>) list +"\n");
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity-B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LowBusInfo.this, LiveLocationInfo.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArrayList("lowStdid", (ArrayList<String>) list);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
Log.d("LLLC", "Passed Value:" + (ArrayList<String>) list +"\n");
startActivity(intent);
```

Activity-C

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<String> list = bundle.getStringArrayList("stdid");
Log.d("LLNC", "Received Value: " + bundle.getStringArrayList("stdid")+"\n");

ArrayList<String> lowList = bundle.getStringArrayList("lowStdid");
Log.d("LLLC", "Received Value: " + bundle.getStringArrayList("lowStdid")+"\n");
```

I coded like this.
When I checked each values(Passed Value from Log.d) from different Activities A,B, it was perfect.

From A list: [null, 305001086, 305001087]

From B list: [null, 305001233, 305001241, 305001010, 305001123, 305001239, 305001273, 305001340, 305001143, 305001352, 305200048, 305001269, 305001275, 305001345, 305001167, 305001237, 305001434, 305001235, 305001354, 305001136, 305001227, 305001094, 305001243, 305001380, 305000887, 305001159, 305001347, 305001247, 305001353, 305001346, 305001171, 305001231, 305001169, 305001086, 305001127, 305200003, 305001341, 305001274, 305001245, 305001155, 305001088, 305001342, 305001271, 305200054, 305001229, 305300257, 305001137, 305001165, 305001153, 305001163]

But the problem is in Activity-C.
I keep getting null from one activity. For example, I get null from B list when I get full A list Value or the opposite situation happens.
I googled whole day finally I found someone says two activities can't be started at once so I matched key the same. But the result was miserably same thing.

Here's the detail purpose:
I wanted to get each data from A,B in C after that I wanted to make condition between A List and B List, refine it and use the code to get other data.

2. Actually I divided activities because of my convenience. If I combine two activities(A,B) into one(but different classes), could be the solution? This is my first question sorry for too long. Thanks in advance.

This runs Activity A then play Activity B.

```
public void mOnClick(View view){
          switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.btnSearch:

                    new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                            data = getRouteInfo();

                            /*Activity B's Method will be executed here*/
                            LowBusInfo lowBusInfo = (LowBusInfo)getApplication();
                            lowBusInfo.getLowBusInfo();

                            lowBusInfo.thread.start();

                            thread.start();

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                @Override
                                public void run(){
                                    textView.setText(data);
                                   }
                            });
                        }
                    }).start();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am not sure, of your use case in getting the data from two activities at the same time, but I would assume after Activity A has performed an action, you would then move to Activity B then Activity C? if not how are these activities triggered? Would just like more context on this so it's easier to help

Comment: Yes it is. Activity A triggers Activity B and then they gathers in Activity C. I made thread to execute Activity B. when Activity A triggers its own Method it triggers Activity B at the same time.

Comment: Why not convert Activity A & B to fragments, then create an Activity to house fragment A & B, then create a data structure that would hold the data created from fragment A & B, this data structure should be put in a ViewModel scoped by the activity i.e Activity context, then after you have created your data from fragment B you can then pass this data structure to your Activity C.

Comment: And yes to answer your question the solution is to combine both activities into one

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem as you said. It works! Have a nice day.